# How to programmatically add header and footer to an existing form-based PDF using iText?

Tags: itext

I need to programmatically add header and footer to an existing form-based PDF using iText. The existing PDF comes from user and it contains no space for header and footer. So the solution is to create a new PDF by concatenating the contents of the existing PDF with the header and footer. However, this approach only works for PDF containing no form. For interactive PDF that contains AcroForm or XFA Form, it fails as follows: (1) AcroForm gets flattened in the new PDF. (2) XFA Form doesn't import at all - the new PDF shows "Please wait...If this message is not eventually replaced by proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document...".

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfGState;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;

public class PdfFormCopyTest {
    private static final String ACRO_FORM_PDF = "AcroForm.pdf";
    private static final String XFA_FORM_PDF = "XfaForm.pdf";
    private static final String NO_FORM_PDF = "NoForm.pdf";
    private static final String ACRO_FORM_PDF_NEW = "AcroForm-new.pdf";
    private static final String XFA_FORM_PDF_NEW = "XfaForm-new.pdf";
    private static final String NO_FORM_PDF_NEW = "NoForm-new.pdf";
    private static final float MARGIN_LEFT = 36.0f;
    private static final float MARGIN_RIGHT = 36.0f;
    private static final float MARGIN_BOTTOM = 56.0f;
    private static final float MARGIN_TOP = 36.0f;
    private static final float FONT_SIZE = 10.0f;
    private static final float MIN_LINE_HEIGHT = FONT_SIZE * 1.5f;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            createPdfFromAcroFormBasedPdf();
            createPdfFromXfaFormBasedPdf();
            createPdfFromFormlessPdf();
        }
        catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void createPdfFromAcroFormBasedPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        System.out.println("Creating new PDF from an existing PDF containing AcroForm.....");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ACRO_FORM_PDF);        
        createNewPdfWithHeaderFooter(reader, ACRO_FORM_PDF_NEW);

        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    private static void createPdfFromXfaFormBasedPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        System.out.println("Creating new PDF from an existing PDF containing XfaForm......");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(XFA_FORM_PDF);
        createNewPdfWithHeaderFooter(reader, XFA_FORM_PDF_NEW);

        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    private static void createPdfFromFormlessPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        System.out.println("Creating new PDF from an existing PDF containing no form......");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(NO_FORM_PDF);
        createNewPdfWithHeaderFooter(reader, NO_FORM_PDF_NEW);

        System.out.println("Success");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new PDF which contains header and footer from the specified input PdfReader object
     * and saves the result as the specified output file.
     * @param reader A PdfReader for the existing PDF.
     * @param outputFileName Name of the PDF file which contains header and footer.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     */
    private static void createNewPdfWithHeaderFooter(PdfReader reader, String outputFileName)
            throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String footer = getFooter();
        String header = getHeader();
        List<Float> footerHeights = computeHeights(footer, reader, Font.NORMAL);
        List<Float> headerHeights = computeHeights(header, reader, Font.BOLD);

        InputStream resizedPdfStream = createPdfWithHeaderFooterSpace(reader, footerHeights, headerHeights);

        PdfStamper stamper = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
            PdfReader newReader = new PdfReader(resizedPdfStream);
            stamper = new PdfStamper(newReader, fos);

            int numberOfPages = stamper.getReader().getNumberOfPages();
            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
                Rectangle rect = stamper.getReader().getPageSize(pageNumber);
                PdfContentByte pageContent = stamper.getOverContent(pageNumber);
                pageContent.saveState();
                pageContent.setGState(new PdfGState());
                renderHeaderFooter(rect, pageContent, header, footer);
                pageContent.restoreState();
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (stamper != null) {
                stamper.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes the height of the specified content for each page
     * in the specified PdfReader with the specified font weight.
     * @param content The string content for which the height of each page is computed.
     * @param reader A PdfReader containing the existing PDF.
     * @param fontWeight The font weight.
     * @return A list of float representing the height of each page.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     */
    private static List<Float> computeHeights(String content, PdfReader reader, int fontWeight)
            throws IOException, DocumentException {
        List<Float> contentHeights = new ArrayList<Float>();

        int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
            Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(pageNumber);
            float height = computeWrappedTextHeight(content, pageSize.getWidth(), fontWeight);
            contentHeights.add(pageNumber - 1, height);
        }

        return contentHeights;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new PDF with place holder for header and footer from the specified parameters.
     * @param reader The PdfReader storing the contents of the PDF to be created.
     * @param footerHeights The footer height for each page.
     * @param headerHeights The header height for each page.
     * @return An InputStream representing the new PDF.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     */
    private static InputStream createPdfWithHeaderFooterSpace(PdfReader reader,
            List<Float> footerHeights, List<Float> headerHeights) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        Document newDocument = null;

        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            newDocument = new Document();
            PdfWriter newPdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(newDocument, baos);
            PdfContentByte newPdfCanvas = null;

            int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
                Rectangle oldPageSize = reader.getPageSize(pageNumber);
                float oldPageWidth = oldPageSize.getWidth();
                float oldPageHeight = oldPageSize.getHeight();
                float footerHeight = footerHeights.get(pageNumber - 1);
                float headerHeight = headerHeights.get(pageNumber - 1);
                float newPageHeight = calculateNewPageHeight(oldPageHeight, headerHeight, footerHeight);
                float newPageWidth = calculateNewPageWidth(oldPageWidth);
                Rectangle newPageSize  = new Rectangle(0, 0, newPageWidth, newPageHeight);
                newDocument.setPageSize(newPageSize);

                if (!newDocument.isOpen()) {
                    newDocument.open();
                    newPdfCanvas = newPdfWriter.getDirectContent();
                }

                float xFactor = 1.0f;
                float yFactor = 1.0f;
                float xOffset = MARGIN_LEFT;
                float yOffset = MARGIN_BOTTOM + footerHeight;

                PdfImportedPage importedPage = newPdfWriter.getImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
                newPdfCanvas.addTemplate(importedPage, xFactor, 0, 0, yFactor, xOffset, yOffset);
                newDocument.newPage();
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (newDocument != null && newDocument.isOpen()) {
                newDocument.close();
            }
        }

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }

    /**
     * Computes the height of the specified string content which must
     * wrap at the specified maximum line width with the specified font weight.
     * @param content The string content for which the height is computed.
     * @param maxLineWidth The maximum line width at which the content must wrap.
     * @param fontWeight The font weight.
     * @return The height of the specified content which wraps at
     * the specified maximum line width with the specified font weight.
     */
    private static float computeWrappedTextHeight(String content, float maxLineWidth, int fontWeight) {
        float totalHeight = 0.0f;

        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, FONT_SIZE);
        font.setStyle(fontWeight);
        BaseFont baseFont = font.getCalculatedBaseFont(true);

        String lineText = "";
        int currentWordStart = -1;
        float lineHeight;

        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < content.length(); charIndex++) {
            String currentChar = content.substring(charIndex, charIndex + 1);
            lineText = lineText + currentChar;
            boolean isCurrentCharWordSeparator = isWordSeperator(currentChar);
            float lineWidth = computeLineWidth(lineText, baseFont);
            if (charIndex == 0 || (!isCurrentCharWordSeparator && currentWordStart < 0)) {
                currentWordStart = charIndex;
            }

            if (lineWidth > maxLineWidth || currentChar.equals("\n")) {
                // Start a new line.
                if (isCurrentCharWordSeparator) {
                    // The current character is a word separator - break the line at the current character.
                    lineHeight = computeLineHeight(lineText, baseFont);

                    // Reset line text.
                    if (currentChar.equals("\n")) {
                        lineText = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        lineText = currentChar;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // The current character is in the middle of a word - break the line at the previous word separator.
                    int lineEnd = lineText.length() - (charIndex - currentWordStart) - 1;
                    if (lineEnd > 0) {
                        String currentWordExcludedLineText = lineText.substring(0, lineEnd);
                        lineHeight = computeLineHeight(currentWordExcludedLineText, baseFont);

                        charIndex = currentWordStart; // New line starts at the beginning of the current word.
                        lineText = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        lineHeight = computeLineHeight(lineText, baseFont);
                        lineText =  currentChar;
                    }
                }

                totalHeight = totalHeight + lineHeight;
            }

            // If it is at a new word break, reset the current word starting index so that
            // the next iteration can set it at the beginning of the next word.
            if (charIndex > 0 && isCurrentCharWordSeparator && currentWordStart >= 0) {
                currentWordStart = -1;
            }
        }

        lineHeight = computeLineHeight(lineText, baseFont);
        totalHeight = totalHeight + lineHeight;

        return totalHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the specified string is a word separator.
     * @param c The string to test.
     * @return true if the specified string is a word separator; false othewise. 
     */
    private static boolean isWordSeperator(String c) {
        return (c.equals("\n") || c.equals("\t") || c.equals(" "));
    }

    /**
     * Computes the line width of the specified line text with the specified base font.
     * @param lineText The line text.
     * @param baseFont A BaseFont object representing the base font of the line.
     * @return A float representing the width of the line.
     */
    private static float computeLineWidth(String lineText, BaseFont baseFont) {
        return baseFont.getWidthPoint(lineText, FONT_SIZE);
    }

    /**
     * Computes the line height with the specified parameters.
     * @param lineText The line text.
     * @param baseFont A BaseFont object representing the base font of the line.
     * @return A float value representing the height of the line.
     */
    private static float computeLineHeight(String lineText, BaseFont baseFont) {
        float lineHeight = baseFont.getAscentPoint(lineText, FONT_SIZE) - baseFont.getDescentPoint(lineText, FONT_SIZE);

        if (lineHeight < MIN_LINE_HEIGHT) {
            lineHeight = MIN_LINE_HEIGHT;
        }

        return lineHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Renders the header and footer to the specified Rectangle with the specified page content, header and footer.
     * @param rect A Rectangle to render the header and footer.
     * @param pageContent A PdfContentByte representing the content of the page.
     * @param header The page header.
     * @param footer The page footer.
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void renderHeaderFooter(Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte pageContent, String header, String footer)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {
        float margin = 36.0f;
        int sides = 2;

        float footerHeight = (float)Math.ceil(computeWrappedTextHeight(footer, rect.getWidth() - margin * sides, Font.NORMAL));
        float headerHeight = (float)Math.ceil(computeWrappedTextHeight(footer, rect.getWidth() - margin * sides, Font.BOLD));
        if (headerHeight < MIN_LINE_HEIGHT) {
            headerHeight = MIN_LINE_HEIGHT;
        }

        // Render header.
        Font headerFont = getDefaultFont();
        headerFont.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        Phrase headerPhrase = new Phrase(header, headerFont);
        ColumnText headerRenderer = new ColumnText(pageContent);
        headerRenderer.setSimpleColumn(headerPhrase, margin, rect.getHeight() - headerHeight - margin + 4,
            rect.getWidth() - margin, rect.getHeight() - margin + 4, MIN_LINE_HEIGHT, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        headerRenderer.go();    

        // Render footer.
        Phrase footerPhrase = new Phrase(footer, getDefaultFont());
        ColumnText footerRender = new ColumnText(pageContent);
        footerRender.setSimpleColumn(footerPhrase, margin, margin, rect.getWidth() - margin, footerHeight + margin, MIN_LINE_HEIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        footerRender.go();
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the height of the new page with the specified parameters.
     * @param oldPageHeight The height of the old page.
     * @param headerHeight The height of header.
     * @param footerHeight The height of footer.
     * @return The height of the new page.
     */
    private static float calculateNewPageHeight(float oldPageHeight, float headerHeight, float footerHeight) {
        return oldPageHeight + MARGIN_TOP + headerHeight + footerHeight + MARGIN_BOTTOM;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the width of the new page with the specified width of old page.
     * @param oldPageWidth The width of the old page.
     * @return The width of the new page.
     */
    private static float calculateNewPageWidth(float oldPageWidth) {
        return oldPageWidth + MARGIN_LEFT + MARGIN_RIGHT;
    }

    private static String getHeader() {
        return "This is dynamically added header.";
    }

    private static String getFooter() {
        StringBuilder footerBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        footerBuilder.append("This is the dynamically added footer.");
        footerBuilder.append("\n\n");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. Footer paragraph 1 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("\n\n");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. Footer paragraph 2 content. ");
        footerBuilder.append("\n\n");
        footerBuilder.append("Footer paragraph 3 content. Footer paragraph 3 content. Footer paragraph 3 content. Footer paragraph 3 content.");

        return footerBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static Font getDefaultFont() {
        return FontFactory.getFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, FONT_SIZE, Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using a version of iText that is at least six and a half years old. There is very little enthusiasm among iText developers to look at questions from people who don't use a more recent version of iText. The professional thing to do would be to use iText 5.5.8.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Yes, the application that I'm working on has extensively and deeply coupled with iText 2.1.7 particularly in areas like table, row and cell. I initially tried to build it with iText 5.5.8 and the result indicates a significant rewrite and test is needed. It'll be too expensive to justify the budget to the management at this stage since everything else related to the old iText 2.1.7 has been working nicely without issue for several years. The problem that I'm facing currently is due to a recent change request to the existing functionality.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I read that you've been using iText for free for more than 6 years and that this saved you plenty of money. How come there is no money left to upgrade?

Comment: All I mean is that it'll take a significant amount of time and effort to rewrite and retest our application to upgrade to iText 5.5.8. So far I haven't seen how upgrading to the newest version can help solve my particular problem. It won't justify the time and budget to the management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to programmatically add header and footer to an existing form-based PDF using iText. The existing PDF comes from user and it contains no space for header and footer. So the solution is to create a new PDF by concatenating the contents of the existing PDF with the header and footer.

No, this is not a good solution. You had better use a `PdfStamper`, change the sizes of the existing pages, and add headers and footers in the new page area. In particular as you use a `PdfStamper` already now for the final step.

@Mark Storer in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090361/1729265) shows how to manipulate the bottom of the **MediaBox**. Likewise you can also change its top. And as Mark remarks in his answer, you may also have to change the **CropBox**.

> However, this approach only works for PDF containing no form. For interactive PDF that contains AcroForm or XFA Form, it fails as follows: (1) AcroForm gets flattened in the new PDF.

With your code the AcroForm form elements should not get *flattened* (i.e. their appearances should not get added to the static PDF content) but they should get *lost*. Sometimes, though, border lines or other indications of form field boundaries actually are already part of the static content. This might be the case for you.

The reason is that your code uses `PdfWriter.getImportedPage`, a method that only takes the page content stream but no interactive features like AcroForm form field widget annotations.

> (2) XFA Form doesn't import at all - the new PDF shows "Please wait...If this message is not eventually replaced by proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document...".

XFA forms are a document type of its own which merely use PDF files as transport medium. Your `PdfWriter.getImportedPage` does not even see the XFA data in the document and only copies a page that your XFA PDF document shows on PDF viewers without XFA support.

In case of XFA forms the PDF page objects usually have no part in what eventually is displayed. Instead the PDF transports an XFA XML. Thus, all your changes to any existing PDF pages remain unseen. You have to extract that XFA XML, manipulate it, and store it again.

iText only has limited support for XFA, and the ancient version you appear to use has none at all.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and correcting many of the wrong assumptions in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for the help and clarification. The AcroForm actually becomes read-only but still visible in the newly generated PDF - AcroForm-new.pdf. I misunderstood it as the result of flattening.

Comment: @RichardXiong If you consider your question answered, please accept it: click on the tick at the left of the answer.

Comment: Yes, Mark's answer helps solve address the issue as follows: (1) For AcroForm, it works. (2) For XFA form, the XFA form remains unchanged as before but the "Please wait..." message is no longer displayed after conversion. Thanks for your help!