# How to extend the page size of existing PDF to add a footer in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to add content in the form a footer with a paragraph centered to all pages of an existing PDF file.
I've followed this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335126/itext-add-content-to-existing-pdf-file/#3343916) but the solution does not solve my issue. Although the code works, my PDFs do NOT have enough bottom margin to fit the footer so the text gets on top of the content.

What I need to do before adding the footer is adding some extra margin at the bottom (effectively extending the page size). Similar to what is done in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775893/how-to-extend-the-page-size-of-a-pdf-to-add-a-watermark) but ONLY that I need to add the extra margin at the bottom instead.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089757/how-do-i-resize-an-existing-pdf-with-coldfusion-itext/#4090361) but didn't work. I'm trying to figure it out myself but no luck so far.

Comment: Why did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090361/2564301) not work?

Comment: Please read [why "doesn't work" is not a problem description that a developer should give](http://lowagie.com/doesntwork) and adapt your question accordingly. **The only possible answer** that can be given to our question *in it's current form* is **"It works for us!"** Also: why are you still using an old iText version; upgrade to iText 7!!!

Comment: It didn't work because my PDFs have other types of boxes. Didn't realize until now. Thank you for your help. Both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to add extra space on the side as explained in this question: [How to extend the page size of a PDF to add a watermark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775893) then you should know how to add extra space to the bottom too. Your question is a duplicate.

The page size of a PDF document is defined using the `/MediaBox`. It can be cropped using the `/CropBox`. In the answer I gave, we change the `/MediaBox` like this:

```
PdfArray mediabox = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
llx = mediabox.getAsNumber(0).floatValue();
mediabox.set(0, new PdfNumber(llx - 36));
```

The value of `llx` is the coordinate of the lower-left X-coordinate, and we subtract half an inch (36 user units).

If you want to change the bottom border, you have to change the lower-left Y-coordinate:

```
PdfArray mediabox = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
lly = mediabox.getAsNumber(1).floatValue();
mediabox.set(1, new PdfNumber(llx - 36));
```

That's what Mark is doing in his answer to the question [How do I resize an existing PDF with Coldfusion/iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089757)

Of course, this won't have any effect if there's a crop box. If there's a crop box, you need to change the `llx` value of the crop box too:

```
PdfArray cropbox = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.CROPBOX);
if (cropbox != null) {
    lly = cropbox.getAsNumber(1).floatValue();
    cropbox.set(1, new PdfNumber(llx - 36));
}
```

Obviously, you need to take the change into account when adding the footer. The bottom coordinate is no longer `lly` but `lly - 36` in my example.

Comment: Solve my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Mention of CROPBOX solved my problem